# Change field options of an embedded Symfony2 form

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to change an option of a field of an embedded form from the parent form?

To illustrate the problem consider this: I have a parent form type class like this:

```
class FruitFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('apple', new AppleFormType())
        ;
    }
```

and a child form type class that is in a separate bundle and I would prefer not to edit, like this:

```
class AppleFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('qty', 'integer', array('label' => 'rubbish label')
        ;
    }
```

and I want to change the label of `qty` to something else, but I want to do this only in the `FruitForm`, not everywhere where the `AppleForm` is used. I had hoped to be able to do something like:

```
class FruitFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('apple', new AppleFormType(), array('qty' => array('label' => 'better label')))
        ;
    }
```

or:

```
class FruitFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('apple', new AppleFormType())
        ;

        $builder->get('apple')->get('qty')->setOption('label', 'better label');
    }
```

but neither of these (and a number of other attempts) have all failed me. There does not exist a `setOption` method that I can see.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I also wanted to change options, the obvious "change the label" case for an existing field from the FOSUserBundle.  I know I could do this in Twig or with translations.

@redbirdo pointed me in the right direction with "it appears that adding a field with the same name will replace it".  Here's the solution:

```
$field = $builder->get('username');         // get the field
$options = $field->getOptions();            // get the options
$type = $field->getType()->getName();       // get the name of the type
$options['label'] = "Login Name";           // change the label
$builder->add('username', $type, $options); // replace the field
```

Comment: $options = $field->getOptions();  didnt work for me, however, $field->getConfig()->getOptions() did the trick ! Thanks again !

Comment: Worked fine for me. @Steven you need to use `$form->get("field")->getOptions()`, or the field with that name doesn't exist yet.

Comment: As a detail, I'm using Symfony 4, and $type = $field->getType()->getName(); doesn't work, (getName is undefined). I had to do : $type = get_class($field->getType()->getInnerType());
If someone has a better idea I'm all for it.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks a lot to @Peter Wooster.
In Symfony 3.0, I had to use something a bit different:

I have a custom Form Type adding fields like so:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('my_field', ChoiceType::class, [
        // Some options here...
        'multiple' => false,
    ]);
}
```

And in another custom Form Type I need to **extend** the Type above and change some options:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $myField = $builder->get('my_field');
    $fieldOptions = $myField->getOptions();
    // Retrieve the FormType. That is the part that is different.
    $fieldType = get_class($myField->getType()->getInnerType());
    $fieldOptions['multiple'] = true;
    // I can obviously put the name 'my_field' directly here
    $builder->add($myField->getName(), $fieldType, $fieldOptions);
}
```

Thanks to the answers above, I hope mine helps!

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```
class AppleFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('qty', 'integer', array('label' => $options['qtyLabel'])
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'qtyLabel' = 'rubbish label';
        );
    }
}
```

and:

```
class FruitFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('apple', new AppleFormType(), array('qtyLabel' => 'better label'))
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know this is an option, but as the `AppleFormType` is in a vendor-bundle I would have to override or replace to get this to work. I was hoping for a solution that could be done entirely in the `FruitFormType` class.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that you'd prefer not to edit it but assumed that you would be ok with overriding it. Would something like $builder->get('apple')->add('qty', 'integer', array('label' => 'better label') be an option? From reading the (2.0) documentation of FormBuilder it appears that adding a field with the same name will replace it but obviously then you'd have to redefine all the options, not just the label...

Comment: EDITED - I found the API for the FormBuilderInterface. It does have get/setAttribute(). Have you tried using $builder->get('apple')->get('qty')->setAttribute('label', 'better label');?

Comment: Yeah that would be ideal, but unfortunately 'label' is an option not an attribute. I tried it before and I just tested again to be extra sure (still doesnt do anything). Ive now started going down the override method. I like the `->add` method you suggested in the comment above, it has its drawbacks as you say, but is the simplest approach suggested (+1 ;))

Comment: Better approach

Answer (score 4):

I am in a case where I can not access the form builder code but have to override a field options to add a `'required' => true`.

Expanding @peter-wooster and @thedamnedrhino reply to a symfony issue on github (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11188) , I end up with this piece of code.

```
$field = $form->get('combinaisons');
$options = $field->getConfig()->getOptions();
$type = $field->getConfig()->getType()->getName();
$options['required'] = true;
unset($options['em']);
$form->add('combinaisons', $type, $options);
```

This works fine with symfony/symfony:2.3.21, doctrine/doctrine-bundle:1.2.0 and doctrine/orm:2.3.6

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the view is often a lot easier for this kind of change.

```
$view->vars['label'] = 'New label';
```

Typically your view will be a parent form, so it might look like this - change from 'Date' > 'Publication date':

```
$view = $form->createView(...);
$view->children['date']->vars['label'] = 'Publication date';
```

If your form is encapsulated in its own type you can use the finishView function:

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->children['date']->vars['label'] = 'Publication date';
}
```

Since most of what is finally passed into the templating engine for rendering is in straight array form, you can mess with quite a lot of stuff at this point.

Comment: Note this change will only apply in the 'current' view. This does not change the form from which the view was built. But I expect this solution will suit many use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by replacing the `qty` field like this:

```
class FruitFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm (FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        
        // Create form you wish to embed
        $appleForm = $builder->create('apple', AppleFormType::class);
        
        // Replace the qty field
        $appleForm->add('qty', 'integer', array('label' => 'better label');
        
        // Embed changed AppleFormType to FruitFormType
        $builder->add($appleForm);
    }

 ...

}
```